# How I can start 2 threads from shell?

Tags: linux, node.js, shell, console

I'm new in shell programming.

1) I want to start 2 node.js processes from *.sh file: 
node script1.js
node script2.js

2) I want to start it when system is loading (on a system start up).

How I can do this?

Comment: Your question title asks for threads, the body of your question asks for processes.  They are, of course, considerably different.  SFAIK no UNIX shells currently support multi-threading, but the Korn shell team is working on adding multi-threading to ksh93.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add [crontab](http://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) entries as well. Use `crontab -e` to edit:

```
@reboot /PATH/TO/SCRIPT1/script1.js
@reboot /PATH/TO/SCRIPT2/script2.js
```

This will start those scripts at startup.

Answer (score 3):

1. To start a process in background, start it with `&` at the end:

   ```
   node script1.js &
   ```
2. What distribution are you using? Startup scripts might be located in `/etc/init.d`

Answer (score 0):

You also need to enable crond service via sys v / BSD init style system. Under RHEL / CentOS / Fedora, you need to use `chkconfig (ntsysv) command` to enable crond on boot:

```
chekconfg crond on
```

Under Debian / Ubuntu Linux use update-rc.d as follows to turn on service on boot:

```
update-rc.d cron defaults
```